# How to create a variable from the value of another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a variable from the value of another variable.  As an example, this would be similar to how I would do this in VFP:

```
nameOfNextVar = "port_no_1";
eval(nameOfNextVar) = 7493
```

Then I will be able to say:

```
alert(port_no_1);
```

And the alert would give me 7493...

Is this possible in JavaScript???

TIA

Dennis

Comment: with eval : duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592630/javascript-variable-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this using JavaScript `eval` method. But using `eval` should be avoid if possible.

```
var nameOfNextVar = "port_no_1";
eval(nameOfNextVar + " = " + 7493);
alert(port_no_1)​;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngTQf/

Other alternative is to define properties on the object or a current instance. You can also use `window` to define variables or properties.

```
var nameOfNextVar = "port_no_1";
this[nameOfNextVar] = 7493;
alert(this.port_no_1);

window[nameOfNextVar] = 7493
alert(window.port_no_1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngTQf/2/

Comment: Yes that works @ShankarSangoli Thank you for the quick response. And thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: And thank you for the alternatives.  I think I like this option better: "window[nameOfNextVar] = ..."  Good suggestion @ShankarSangoli

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb, you should try avoid eval when possible. However, if there is no other way, then you could do this:

```
nameOfNextVar = "port_no_1";
eval("var " + nameOfNextVar + " = 7493");
alert(port_no_1);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you rock...  It is similar to how we do it in VFP, but this eval simply evaluates the text. In VFP you can say "print eval(nameOfNextVar)" and get back 7493.  Can that be done in JavaScript??

Comment: you could have `eval("print " + nameOfNextVar );`.

Comment: Actually, I tried it and id does the eval like VFP.  Many thanks, @ralfe